# ruby on rails, meta_search and case insensitive oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle, case-sensitive, meta-search

I am using meta_search gem on my rails project.  The database is an Oracle database and "like" is case sensitive.   Does somebody know how I can create a new condition, or something, for get queries like this:

```
UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER('User Firstname')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[meta_search method class](http://rdoc.info:8080/github/ernie/meta_search/MetaSearch/Method) - first two code samples. Just instead of `:backwards_name` rewrite it to be `:incasesensitive_name` or whatever you want and add such text field to your search form.

`UPPER()` is built into Oracle AFAIR, so scope may look like this:

```
scope :incasesensitive_name, lambda {|name| where('UPPER(name) LIKE ?', "%#{name.upcase}%")}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs to do this with ransack:

```
ransacker :subject_cs, :formatter => proc {|v| v.downcase }, :splat_param => true, :type => :string do
    arel_table[:subject].lower
end
```

Comment: Just tried this with rism's oracle-enhanced gem, Rails 4, oracle 9i and it worked great! In my case, name_cs_cont generates sql including ```WHERE ((LOWER("FOOTBALL_PLAYER"."FIRST_NAME") LIKE '%brady%'```

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, glad i could help